# Prove that an absolutely continuous cdf is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, continuity

Let $F(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ be an absolutely continuous distribution function. How to prove that $F$ is continuous? Thank you.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that $F$ defines a (nonnegative) measure on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ which is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$?

Comment: @Matt Rosenzweig Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the [Radon-Nikodym theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem), there exists a nonnegative function $f:\mathbb{R}^{d}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfying

$$F(x_{1},\ldots,x_{d})=\int_{-\infty}^{x_{1}}\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{x_{d}}f(y_{1},\ldots,y_{d})dy_{1}\cdots dy_{d}$$

Let $h\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and fix $x\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$. Let $\chi_{x+h}$ be the indicator function of the set $\prod(-\infty,x_{i}+h_{i}]$. It is evident that $f\chi_{x+h}(y)\rightarrow f\chi_{x}(y)$ pointwise a.e. as $h\rightarrow 0$, and the function $f\chi_{x+h}$ is dominated by $f$. So by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem,

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}F(x+h)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}f(y)\chi_{x+h}(y)dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}f(y)\chi_{x}(y)dy=F(x_{1},\ldots,x_{d})$$